# What tense is this? 'Despite their already having paid the money...'

Tags: tense, aspect, gerund-clauses

I was reading a piece of writing recently and I came across a very strangely phrased sentence that took me a while to understand. Can anyone identify the sentence's tense or really just what makes it so strange?

> Despite their already having paid the money, there was an additional tax.

Comment: "already having paid the money" works as a noun, it can be replaced by "payment" for instance: "Despite their payment, there was an additional tax."

Comment: *their already having paid the money* is a non-finite clause--it is headed by a gerund perfect *having paid*, which has no tense (though the perfect construction casts the payment as prior to the action of the matrix clause). As @MorganFR says, such clauses ordinarily "act like" nouns; here it the object of the preposition *despite*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[despite](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/despite) is a preposition meaning **not prevented by**. A preposition normally attaches a noun to a sentence, for example:

> He completed the marathon, despite **his age**.

**already having paid the money** is a noun phrase. We can include a verb in a noun phrase using either a gerund or an infinitive: in this case, a [gerund](http://www.myenglishteacher.net/gerunds.html) is used. We make the present form of a gerund by putting **-ing** on the end of the verb- this is quite common- but we can also make the past gerund form by putting **having** in front of the perfect form- thus, **having paid**.

The main verb in the sentence is **was**, which is past simple. The strange bit in this sentence is the perfect form of the gerund, **having paid**.

There are fewer opportunities to use the past form of a gerund than the present form, and in addition, according to this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=having%20paid&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chaving%20paid%3B%2Cc0), its usage has declined steadily over the past 200 years.

Comment: Do you know if writing in this way was ever common in english?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is _uncommon_ in modern English. Having made that assertion, I will now end this comment.

Comment: @MorellaAlmann, I have added an NGram to my answer that charts the decline in usage of the perfect from of the gerund.

Comment: If you include up to 2008, it looks like it is making a slight comeback: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=having+paid&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chaving%20paid%3B%2Cc0 Seriously, though - I tried several different verbs (made, walked, driven, writ, gone) and the same decline you pointed out was there for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

> Despite their already having paid the money, there was an additional tax.

*-ing* words are not verbs, but either participles (if modifiers) or gerunds (if nouns).

To wrap your head around the form of the sentence, consider this simpler one:

> Despite the rules, there was an additional tax.

So here is an examination of what is going on with the original sentence and how to understand it.

- "Their already having paid the money" is the object of the preposition *despite*.
- Objects of prepositions (objects in general) have to be nouns.
- Gerunds can have a subject and object like normal, real verbs.
- Subjects of gerunds are expressed using object pronouns.  *Me walking to the store made my mom angry.*
- Objects of gerunds go after the gerund just like real verbs.  Here's a rather twisted example:  *He had two dollars.  Him giving her them made his sister jealous.*
- It's possible for gerunds to be in most if not all of the tenses requiring auxillary verbs *be* or *have*.  It looks like this: *Them having been at the movie yesterday prevented them from being a suspect in the murder,* *Her having had two kids did not diminish her beauty in his eyes.*

The real sujbect of that sentence is *there* and the verb is *was*.  Prepositional phrases often modify or qualify phrases and that is what *despite X* is doing here.

Comment: "Subjects of gerunds are expressed using object pronouns" - in this case given by the OP, "their already having paid the money" uses the **possessive determiner** "their", and I think possessive determiners would also work better in your examples. Would you agree?

Comment: Yep, determiners in general will work because its a noun and they will imply a subject as well.

Comment: For more detail on genitive vs accusative with gerunds: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner