# Two kinds of the subject

Tags: sentence-choice, gerund-clauses

Is the first sentence correct? Does it have the same meaning as the second one?

> 1. Him knowing four languages helped him with getting a job.
> 2. The fact that he knows four languages helped him with getting a job.

Comment: "Getting". Two t's. Although you could say "helped him get a job". I think sentence one should be "*His* knowing four...", but either way sentence 2 sounds better to my ear.

Comment: "Getting". Sure.

Comment: Knowing four languages helped him get a job.

Comment: I would not use "him" in any formal context. I think it is unnecessary without some specific reason for using it.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is correct, and has the same meaning as the second one, but it is awkward. The one suggested by AlanCarmack (without "him") would be the preferable phrasing.

See also other questions tagged [gerund-clause](/questions/tagged/gerund-clause).

Comment: Depends how pedantic you want to be. Traditionally, it should be *his knowing ...*.

Comment: That's the reason I referred to other questions. Specifically [this one](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/90323/27840).

Comment: *Him knowing* sounds awkward to me, but *his knowing* doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's all a matter of what kind of English we're talking about here.

The first sentence is a possessive gerund. In formal English, I believe *Him knowing* is incorrect; it would be *His knowing* instead. But here's a person who says this kind of traditional grammar is "rubbish":

https://jakubmarian.com/his-doing-vs-him-doing-possessives-and-gerunds-in-english/

I don't necessarily agree with him. I think *his knowing* is a little more precise than *him knowing*. I guess I'm old-fashioned.